# how display html body part content from web url

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.details);

    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    WebView detailsLink=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    detailsLink.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    detailsLink.loadUrl(bundle.getString("keyLink"));
}
```

This displays the whole html page in android webview field, but I have to display body part in my web view.  I tried query for this but it is not working.

```
String detailsLink1="<html><body><iframe src='keyLink' width='100%' height='100' scrolling='no'> </iframe></body></html>";      
detailsLink.loadData(detailsLink1, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
URL url = new URL("your url");

InputStream is = url.openStream();

byte[] b = new Byte[size of data you want to read];

String s = new String(b);
```

and now store or display this string where ever you want.

Comment: please send me complte detail or send ur email adress so that i can send u my project u can do it please help me i need immidiate response i have dead line

Comment: here is my email id send me the code i will try to salove your problem. e_id ---> code_pravesh@yahoo.com